# Spring boot: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed;

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I am using building a simple spring boot application which should connect to a PostgreSQL database and proivde server functionality by sending and receiving JSON requests and responses. It is a maven project.

These are my pom.xml dependencies

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSTL for JSP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180130</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

This is the only controller I'm using right now.

```
        package com.server.controller;

    import com.server.entity.User;
    import com.server.service.UserService;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

    import java.util.List;

    @RestController
    public class UserController {

        @Autowired
        UserService userService;
        @RequestMapping(value = "/users/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ResponseEntity<User> getUserById(@PathVariable Long id) {
            return new ResponseEntity<User>(userService.findById(id),HttpStatus.OK);
        }

        @Autowired
  @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getUsers() {
        return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(userService.getAll(),HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @Autowired
    @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> createAccount(@RequestBody User user) {
        userService.create(user);
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Successful!", HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

This is the implementation of User

```
    package com.server.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "login")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "userID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    long id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    String password;

    public User() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * User constructor.
     * @param username Receives a username String.
     * @param password Receives a password String.
     */
    public User(String username, String password) {
        super();
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

This is the main class of the server

```
    package com.server;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration.class,DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
        HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class, JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class})
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.server.service.UserService")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.server.repository.UserRepository")
class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }

}
```

I have looked at all of the other questions related to this exception which I could find and none of them seem to work. Things that I tried are removing and adding certain dependencies, and changing the `exclude` line inside `@EnableAutoConfiguration`.

The full exception message is

```
    Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-03-05 02:21:54.857 ERROR 8662 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:740) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at com.server.Main.main(Main.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:450) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaMetamodelMappingContext.<init>(JpaMetamodelMappingContext.java:55) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.createInstance(JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java:80) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.createInstance(JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java:44) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractFactoryBean.java:141) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

I am very new to spring boot, so missing something obvious is not out of the question.
Help is very much appreciated

Comment: remove `@EnableJpaRepositories("com.server.repository.UserRepository")` ?  see https://www.concretepage.com/questions/555

Comment: Why did you add manual auto-configuration excludes in the first place?

Comment: Removing the `@EnableJpaRepositories` worked, thank you! The auto-config excludes are there to fix another error that I ran into earlier, though only 1 of them is in fact necessary, thanks for pointing it out as well.

Comment: Replace all annotations on the `Main` with a single `@SpringBootApplication` class. Also remove the `@Autowired` annotation on the methods in  your controller (mixing `@Autowired` on an `@RequestMapping` annotated method doesn't make sense).